# How to install working Play Store on a clean device (CWM13 ROM)?

Tags: cyanogenmod, google-play-store, samsung-galaxy-s-3, 6.0-marshmallow, google-play-services

I did a factory reset recently, and when I installed the latest version of Play Store and Google Play Services on my Android 6.0.1 device from [APKMirror](http://www.apkmirror.com/), it keeps showing `Unfortunately, Google Play Services has stopped`. Well, I have CWM13 ROM installed on my device, the app settings doesn't have the "Clear Cache" option, so I can't fix it in the common way.

Any ideas guys? Thx in advance.

Comment: You have to flash Gapps immediately after flashing a ROM to avoid such issues.

Comment: @GokulNC What happen if I don't flash Gapps immediately? Does it brick the phone or some sort?

Comment: @HappyFace Infinite bootloop.

Answer (score 0):

While in recovery, you need to flash the ROM and then without booting to that ROM, flash gapps. If you're using TWRP MultiROM you can still boot into other installed ROMs without bootlooping the one you just flashed. If you're using regular old TWRP, just flash the OS and gapps all in one go.

Comment: Oh, and check on XDA for whatever files you need before going other places like APK mirror.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to find GAPPS (google apps) that match your android version you can find it on opengapps.org 
And than you need to do system, data, cache and cust wipes.
Than you need to flash ROM and than flash GAPPS right after flashing ROM.